# Get selected text with format using javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically, I want style of selected text. Suppose, I have a full text "Hello world to sample application" placed in div. Then I made a word "Hello" in bold. I want to retrieve style of word "Hello" word and not of whole div. 
There is one method "getCommandValue" method available but not working with Firefox.
"getComputedStyle" method gives style of the object and not of selected text in div.

Comment: Let's *not* 'suppose.' Let's actually *see some code*, and a clear explanation of the expected interaction, and what the outcome/output should be. Post the code *here*, post a *demo* at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='mydiv'><span id='boldword'>Hello</span> world to sample application</div>
```

Then f.e. with jQuery:

```
$('#boldword').css('font-weight');
```

.css(*attribute*) gives you the current value for an attribute, .css(*attribute*, *value*) sets a news value for the given attribute.

I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply but suppose if I made "to" and "application"

Comment: Original : <div id='mydiv'>Hello world to sample application</div> After applying bold on it : <div id='mydiv'><b>Hello</b> world to sample application</div>. How to get word "Hello" with its css format as <b>Hello</b>

Comment: Basically I don't want to add span tag with id to retrieve the value.

Comment: @user1584122 Use a class instead